# Flutter Model Class for Cloud Firestore Subcollections

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following Cloud Firestore structure and Model Class below. But I don't know how implement the Model Class to get the Data from subcollection:

[image]

```
class UserModel {
  final String id;
  final String email;
  List<PersonModel> people;

  UserModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
    List<PersonModel>? people,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return UserModel(
      id: data['id'],
      email: data['email'],
      people: data['people']
          .map<PersonModel>((person) => PersonModel.fromJson(person))
          .toList(),
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'email': email,
        'people': people.map((person) => person.toJson()).toList(),
      };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a separate model class representing the subcollection and fetch the data to this model class from the subcollection. You can then pass that into the original model class.

Comment: @ralemos do you have an example of "fetch the data to this model class from the subcollection" ?